# EmberJS - How to remove an object from hasMany relationship and then repush it?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, relationship

I try to remove a model from a relationship and later import it again by using `pushPayload`.

The relationship is only updated on one side but not an the reverse side.

```
this.get('store').pushPayload({
  folder: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'My folder'
  }
});

this.get('store').pushPayload({
  item: {
    id: 2,
    name: 'My item',
    parentFolder: 1
  }
});

var folder = this.get('store').peekRecord('folder', 1);
var item = this.get('store').peekRecord('item', 2);

console.log('Parent folder id: ', item.get('parentFolder.id'), 'Items length', folder.get('items.length'));
item.get('parentFolder').get('items').removeObject(item);
console.log('Parent folder id: ', item.get('parentFolder.id'), 'Items length', folder.get('items.length'));

this.get('store').pushPayload({
  item: {
    id: 2,
    name: 'My item',
    parentFolder: 1
  }
});
console.log('Parent folder id: ', item.get('parentFolder.id'), 'Items length', folder.get('items.length'));
```

I would expect to get the following output:

```
Parent folder id:  1 Items length 1
Parent folder id:  undefined Items length 0
Parent folder id:  1 Items length 1
```

But I get this one:

```
Parent folder id:  1 Items length 1
Parent folder id:  undefined Items length 0
Parent folder id:  1 Items length 0
```

The issue is the last `Items length`.

https://ember-twiddle.com/d58d95d5be0cc8750282b9cc48db6489

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unload the record if you are going to use `pushPayload` to add it back in and you wish the payload to "win" over what you have locally on relationships:

```
item.get('parentFolder').get('items').removeObject(item);
this.get('store').unloadRecord(item);
this.get('store').pushPayload({
  item: {
    id: 2,
    name: 'My item',
    parentFolder: 1
  }
});
```

Comment: It works on my example but not in my actual app. This seems also a bit dirty to completely remove the model. At no point it was removed by the user...

Answer (score 1):

I reworked your twiddle with annotated comments on what happens with each push.  The difference between `push` and `pushPayload` is that the latter calls the former once it has normalized the data into the format you see here.

https://ember-twiddle.com/c65c33ce0b1810258b75b5679b75d0e4?fileTreeShown=false&openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C

The short answer is that `folder` has local state (the removal of the item) that must be cleared in order for your server changes to take effect.  While unloadRecord is one way to achieve this, that is an accidental side-effect and there are many better ways (one is shown in my twiddle using `push`, you could also do a `pushObject` to put the item back that you removed).